# Write a Query to Arrange Product and Category of DB table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one for product and another is category

I have a table with category and subcategory field. I want the summation of different subcategory under a particular category. Like Table

```
cat_id| category | 
------+--------------+--
1     |  Cloth       |  
2     |  Food       |  
3     |  Fuel        |  
4     |  School      |
```

and another one is product table

```
  id|    name   |  cat_id |
 ------+-----------+---------+--
    1  |  skirt    |  1
    2  |  shirt    |  1
    3  |  St Xavier|  4
    4  |  Petrol   |  3
```

Now i want result to be

```
  id  |    name   |  cat_name |
------+-----------+---------+--
   1  |  skirt    |  Cloth
   2  |  shirt    |  Cloth
   3  |  St Xavier|  School
   4  |  Petrol   |  School
```

What will be the My Sql Query for it, Kindly help !!!

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT p.`id` AS "id" , p.`name`AS "Product Name",c.`category`AS "Category" 
FROM `product` p
INNER JOIN `category`c ON (p.`cat_id`=c.`cat_id`)  
ORDER BY p.`id` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, B.category AS cat_name 
FROM product A, category B 
WHERE A.cat_id=B.cat_id
```